# Вывод AlertDialog'a в IntentService'e

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin

Ребята, есть задача, не знаю как подойти.
В методе `override onHandleIntent` есть `try catch`, в который мне нужно засунуть вывод `AlertDialog`, как правильно это сделать, я не знаю, так как тут интерфейса нет(+ получается придётся стучатсья в активити)?

Код класса

```
class GcmRegistrationIntentService : IntentService("GcmRegistrationIntentService") {

override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    try {
        val gcmSenderId = FlavorSettings.gcmSenderId
        val systemToken = if (gcmSenderId.isEmpty()) gcmSenderId
            else InstanceID.getInstance(this).getToken(gcmSenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)
        if (PreferenceRepository.gcmToken != systemToken) {
            PreferenceRepository.gcmToken = systemToken
            if (UserSession.isUserSignedIn() && ProfilesRepository.lastProfile() != null) {
                JobManager.scheduleAutoSync()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.log()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Добавьте ваш код и опишите подробнее проблему. Какого интерфейса и где нет?

Comment: @eugeneek обновил вопрос.

Comment: Чтобы показать `AlertDialog` из `IntentService` у него должен быть тип `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, и для этого нужен соответствующий пермишн. Опишите ваш сценарий использования. Возможно вам не нужен именно диалог и подойдёт что-то другое, например нотификейшн.

Comment: @eugeneek дело в том, что при отлове ошибки я так раз таки должен выводить пользователю диалог. Но как его сюда всунуть немного затрудняюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А задумка из комментария на самом деле неплохая.

В своём сервисе стучитесь с помощью EventBus'a в класс:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(ErrorEvent())
```

В самом классе ErrorEvent в зависимости от Ваших потребностей добавляйте нужные поля.

Ну а далее, то место(фрагмент/активити) в которое вы хотите поместить реализуйте Ваш AllertDialog в методе onEvent, передавая в него аргументы этого пустого класса(также дополнительно в аннотацию стоит прописать ThreadMode.MAIN):

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onEvent(event: ErrorEvent) {
    //some functions ...
}
```

Ну и не забывайте в этом классе в методе `onStart` реализовать:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
```

И в методе `onStop`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
```

**Upd**:

Так как Android по умолчанию строит работу приложения в один процесс, то волноваться не стоит по поводу их работы в разных процессах. Если же Вы не уверены, то загляните в `AndroidManifest.xml` и просмотрите атрибут `process` в Вашем приложении и убедитесь что нет различий.

Comment: не знаю почему, но метод onEvent не запускается(

Comment: @Inkognito а до этого все шаги проходят? Пробовали дебажить, отлавливать логами?

Comment: Спасибо, вызывал не в той активити прост.

Answer (score 4):

Вывод диалога из `Service` является антипаттерном. Сервис - это по определению то что **должно** работать в фоне и естественно пытаться из него что-то вывести на уровень UI выглядит мягко говоря сомнительно.

Рекомендуемые варианты:

1. Отправить бродкаст, который будет выловлен *где-то* и обработан
2. Вывести нотификацию или тоаст
3. Воспользоваться стандартным паттерном взаимодействия сервиса с `Activity` и уже в `Activity` обработать диалог.

Но если уж совсем неймется, то посмотрите [лайфхак предлагаемый в Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148192/)

**Update**

По поводу хаков с `EventBus/otto/rxJava` отвечу [лишь одной цитатой](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html):

> A common misunderstanding about Android multitasking is the difference between a process and an application. In Android these are not tightly coupled entities: applications may seem present to the user without an actual process currently running the app; multiple applications may share processes, or one application may make use of multiple processes depending on its needs; the process(es) of an application may be kept around by Android even when that application is not actively doing something.

В вольном переводе это означает, что невозможно гарантировать, что приложение и сервис будут всегда находиться в пределах одного процесса.

Коли уж так, то наверное **иногда** связка `Activity-Service` через `EventBus` будет работать, но это же наверное не совсем то чего мы хотим, не правда ли?

Comment: А если пойти немного иным способом, из сервиса попробовать стучаться в активити с помощью EventBus'a и в самой активити уже реализовать диалог?

Comment: Да задрали своим `EventBus/Otto/rxJava` - из сервиса в общем случае [это не работает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568181/otto-eventbus-across-multiple-processes) (`Service` и `Activity` могут находиться в разных процессах)

Comment: @Barmaley А если использовать одну активность, то интересно как сервис сможет быть в другом процесе?

Comment: Элементарно Ватсон - заданием именованного атрибута `android:process`

Comment: @Barmaley тогда не понимаю в чём прикол "не любви" к EventBus'у, для сервиса и активити прописываете использование одного процесса и вуаля. Да и по умолчанию Android всё в 1 процесс кидает.

Comment: См. апдейт ответа

Comment: Поддержу @Barmaley, в "не любви" :) Хайп по поводу всяких Bus-ов уже улегся, многие поняли, что это выглядит красиво во всяких туториалах и hello world-ах, но с увеличением сложности приложения, сложность понимания откуда-куда-почему и в каком порядке что улетает и прилетаем растет по экспоненте. Как результат, баги которые никто не может отловить и т.п.